# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null when trying to display a result in a quiz

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having issues in regards of a basic quiz I'm creating, I have the questions displayed when having the page loading, but for whatever reason, I'm having issues having the results display and I cannot figure out how it isn't working.

**edit"" The error is on line 88 at line 29 when checking inspect element suggesting that that there is an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onClick' of null

Below are the HTML file and JS files that are a part of the quiz

```js
var myQuestions = [
   {
    question: "What is the remainder of 21 divided by 7",
    answers: {
     a: '21',
     b: '7',
     c: '0',
     d: '3'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'd'
   },
   {
    question: "What is the square of 15",
    answers: {
     a: '15',
     b: '30',
     c: '252',
     d: '225'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'd'
   }
  ];

  var quizContainer = document.getElementById('quiz');
  var resultsContainer = document.getElementById('answer');
  var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

  generateQuiz(myQuestions, quizContainer, resultsContainer, submitButton);

  function generateQuiz(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer, submitButton){

   function showQuestions(questions, quizContainer){
    var output = [];
    var answers;

    for(var i=0; i<questions.length; i++){
     
     answers = [];

     for(letter in questions[i].answers){

      answers.push(
       '<label>'
        + '<input type="radio" name="question'+i+'" value="'+letter+'">'
        + letter + ': '
        + questions[i].answers[letter]
       + '</label>'
      );
     }

     output.push(
      '<div class="question">' + questions[i].question + '</div>'
      + '<div class="answers">' + answers.join('') + '</div>'
     );
    }

    quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join('quiz');
   }


   function showResults(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer){
    
    var answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll('.answers');
    
    var userAnswer = '';
    var numCorrect = 0;
    
    for(var i=0; i<questions.length; i++){

     userAnswer = (answerContainers[i].querySelector('input[name=question'+i+']:checked')||{}).value;
     
     if(userAnswer===questions[i].correctAnswer){
      numCorrect++;

      answerContainers[i].style.color = 'lightgreen';
     }
     else{
      answerContainers[i].style.color = 'red';
     }
    }

    resultsContainer.innerHTML = numCorrect + ' out of ' + questions.length;
   }

   showQuestions(questions, quizContainer);
   
   submitButton.onClick = function(){
    showResults(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer);
   }
  
  }
```

```html
<button onClick="showResults()">Results</button>
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Would appreciate any help given

lines 29 and 88 will be shown below

```
This is line 29
generateQuiz(myQuestions, quizContainer, resultsContainer, submitButton);
```

```
            submitButton.onClick = function(){
                showResults(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer);
            }
```

Comment: What do you specifically mean by *I'm having issues having the results display and I cannot figure out how it isn't working.*? Are you getting an error? if so, what line is it on?

Comment: its on line 88 at 29 on the javascript file (completely forgot to add that in sorry)

Comment: Yes, but we don't know what that line of code is. What code is on line 88? We're not mind readers. Please ask pointed, specific questions and don't expect us to do simple research for you.

Comment: I've just edited it to point out what the lines are

Comment: The error suggests that `submitButton` is null, i.e. that `document.getElementById('submit');` didn't find the button element.

Comment: that's what's frustrating me I did include a button inside of the HTML

Comment: Make sure you include your `script` at the end of the `body` of the document, not in the `head` section. That way, by the time the script runs, all of the HTML will have been parsed into memory.

Answer (score -1):

Actually your problem is that your "showResults" function is not declared in global level scope, you must move it out of "generateQuiz"

Comment: HTML is not case-sensitive. Either of those is ok.

Comment: You are right, just edited my answer, its scope issue, he must move his function and edit his code a little bit